# View files on Disk

Tags: oracle, file, view

I have a log file, and I'd like to have other users view this log file.   I am sure I can access it via some external table structure, but that would not be easy to set up given how the log is.

We are on 11g.  Is there any way just to "view" a test file from say SqlDeveloper?

Comment: Why would you involve a **database** into viewing a **filesystem** object (i.e. a log file)? Let them access it via ... Windows Explorer, not SQL Developer.

Comment: Unfortunately on this application, the people viewing the log do not have access to the Linux filesystem.   So, we are hoping for some table or such they can just view......